# How to have a print output stored on a variable (after escaping)

Tags: python, string, encoding, escaping

I have a variable A equal to :

```
A = '$\\epsilon_1$\n'
```

When we print the variable, we are obtaining this :

```
print(A)
$\epsilon_1$
```

How can I store this output on a variable?
From A, I want B equal to :

```
B = '$\epsilon_1$'
```

Thank you!

Comment: Yeah but I want to store '$\epsilon_1$' instead of this '$\\epsilon_1$\n' on the variable.
I have a file that contain  '$\epsilon_1$'  but when I read it, it becomes '$\\epsilon_1$\n' because of the escape.

Answer (score 1):

Strip off the `\n` from `A` and assign it to `B`.

```
A = '$\\epsilon_1$\n'
B = A.strip('\n')
print(f'B: {B}')

# Output:
# B: $\epsilon_1$
```

Comment: It doesn't work, with that we will still have the first backslash (it becomes $\\epsilon_1$)

Comment: Did you run my code directly on Terminal or from a file ?

Comment: on a terminal. You are obtaining $\epsilon_1$  because you are using the print function. But when you try to see what is stored on B you will have $\\epsilon_1$ (with 2 backslash)

Comment: Terminal shows escape sequences and ```print``` does not. The value of ```B``` will not change whether you change in on Terminal or using ```print```.

Comment: Ah yeah, you're right it works with strip! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Walid16 Glad to hear that! Please upvote and accept my answer.